Moving the vertical scrollbar with scrolling on the page
First, take a look at the following code:


window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  document.body.style.setProperty('--scroll', window.pageYOffset / (document.body.offsetHeight - window.innerHeight));
}, false);
.top-line {
    width: 7px;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: auto;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2000;
    background-color: #f00;
    border-radius: 0;
    animation: bottom-line 1s linear;
    -webkit-animation: bottom-line 1s linear;
    -moz-animation: bottom-line 1s linear;
    -o-animation: bottom-line 1s linear;
    -ms-animation: bottom-line 1s linear;
}

@keyframes bottom-line {
    to {
      background-color: #f00;
      height: 0%;
    }
  }

 :root .top-line {
    animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-delay: calc(var(--scroll) * -1s);
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
}
<div class="top-line"></div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>



As you can see in the code above, the left navigation bar starts moving with the main page scroll. But this movement is wrong because the left scrollbar reaches the end before the main page scroll reaches the end.
I want the left scrollbar to be 0% at first (hidden) and then when the main scroll starts moving from top to bottom, the left scrollbar moves up from bottom to top in the opposite direction of the main scroll.

This can be accomplished via pure CSS. Use animation-timeline:scroll(y) instead. (Can I use animation-timeline on my browser?)
When you scroll down the animation steps forward and grows the top-line. Also, it should use position:fixed instead to maintain position based on the viewport.


.filler {
  height: 300vh;
}

.top-line {
  width: 7px;
  position: fixed;
  /*updated*/
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 2000;
  background-color: #f00;
  border-radius: 0;
  animation: bottom-line 1s linear;
  animation-timeline: scroll(y);
  /*added*/
}

@keyframes bottom-line {
  0% {
    height: 0vh;
  }
  100% {
    height: 100vh;
  }
}
<div class="top-line"></div>
<div class="filler"></div>




As a workaround if animation-timeline:scroll() is not supported, one solution is to use JavaScript to update the height instead.


function getScrollPercent() {
  var h = document.documentElement,
    b = document.body,
    st = 'scrollTop',
    sh = 'scrollHeight';
  return (h[st] || b[st]) / ((h[sh] || b[sh]) - h.clientHeight) * 100;
}

function update() {
  document.getElementById("left-line").style.height = getScrollPercent() + "vh";
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  update();
});
update();
.filler {
  height: 300vh;
}

.top-line {
  width: 7px;
  height: 0vh;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 2000;
  background-color: #f00;
  border-radius: 0;
}
<div id="left-line" class="top-line"></div>
<div class="filler"></div>




Hi there. The navigation bar is positioned correctly, but why does it animate automatically? I don't want the navigation bar to have an animation; it should simply move based on the user's scrolling.

@wp-php It is moving solely based on user's scrolling. I'm not sure what are you referring to "animated automatically". Is your JavaScript code still running? Did you remove your unnecessary :root .top-line selector?

I want to use the scroll event, but CSS doesn't support events, so I need to use a bit of JavaScript as well. I tried your solution, but when I scroll, the scrollbar only appears and doesn't move.

Oh, are you on Firefox or Safari? animation-timeline is not widely supported yet. If that's the issue, I could add a JavaScript solution.

My goal is to run on Chrome and Firefox. I am currently testing with Firefox. It works well in Chrome.

Added a JavaScript Solution. Not sure if there is a more efficient way.

It worked correctly in Chrome, but in Firefox, it automatically scrolls upwards without scrolling its scrollbar.

Yeah, because without animation-timeline:scroll() it will be just a normal animation. The JS solution should be working though.

Thank you very much. Now it works well in both Firefox and Chrome.
